# Access entire igniteRDD cache from worker

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ignite

How can I efficiently access an entire igniteRDD cache (ignite for spark cache) from a spark worker?

Comment: Have you tried the samples from https://www.gridgain.com/resources/blog/apacher-ignitetm-and-apacher-sparktm-integration-using-ignite-rdds?

Comment: Yes I have but I can't see the way how each spark worker can access all the data from cache without doing fully replication.